# declaring and using enums and structs with C for C++ developers

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, struct, enums

I wanted to know when a `typedef` should be used with structs/enums in C.
I believe the same principal applies to objective-C

Suppose I have something like this

```
@interface foo : UIViewController
...

enum PlayState {Start , Stop , Pause};

@end
```

Then in the implementation file I have this

```
@implementation foo

-(void) SomeMethod : (PlayState) val  /// <----Eror : How do I set PlayState as a parameter
{
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joys of C...

In (Objective-)C the name introduced by an `enum` (or `struct`) definition is not standalone, to use it you must prefix it with `enum`. So your example can be written:

```
enum PlayState {Start , Stop , Pause};

- (void) SomeMethod:(enum PlayState)val
```

C also allows any type to be given a shorthand using `typedef`, so you can add to the above:

```
typedef enum PlayState PlayState;
```

Note that the two `PlayState`'s are different - one is an `enum` identifier and the other a type name - and C can always tell from the context which you mean.

Now you can just use `PlayState`:

```
- (void) SomeOtherMethod:(PlayState)val
```

(and `enum PlayState` is still valid).

C then allows you to combine the `enum` and `typedef` into one, giving:

```
typedef enum PlayState {Start , Stop , Pause} PlayState;
```

and finally as you now have `PlayState` as a type name you will probably never use `enum PlayState` so C allows you to drop the tag:

```
typedef enum {Start , Stop , Pause} PlayState;
```

but `enum PlayState` is now no longer valid.

All the above also applies to `struct`.

Comment: I am very comfortable with C++ but this was one of my main confusions with C . This is the best explanation I have read so far using typedefs with structs and enums. I will readjust my question and add a c tag to this

Answer (score 1):

Change enum declaration:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    Start,
    Stop,
    Pause,
} PlayState;
```